# iOS in app purchases. Sending private mail to user regarding payment to use more server space

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have an app where free users get less storage space on my server, and premium users get more storage space on my server. All functionality inside the app is the same. But if a free user passes their storage limit, their files will no longer sync.

If I don't specify any external link or button for the payment in the application and send private mail to user from server to pay on website to sync their files.. will apple approve this ?

Comment: You can do this, as long as it happens not within the app. If you send an email, you can link/do what you want. If you send a push or in app notification, I would not link to your website (if you are not using IAPs)

Comment: What if I send the push notification as "You got the new mail from app." and in the mail I will specify link for payment.

Comment: You can't link to the mail, so I don't know if the push makes sense. I'd either send the push "You reached your account limit, we've sent you an email with more details" or something like that. Usually Apple doesn't test these cases.